# xRDP reinstalled on Ubuntu 22.04.3. Can't get it to load into Gnome desktop instead of xfce

Tags: gnome, xfce, remote-desktop

I have an Ubuntu setup, 22.04.3 lts.  A while back I set it up using xrdp and xfce4 and xfce4-goodies.  When I RDP to that computer I get the xfce desktop.

I then set up another Ubuntu setup for xRDP, but without installing xfce. When I RDP to that computer I get the gnome desktop.

I want to change the first one to look like the 2nd, ie use the gnome desktop instead of xfce for xrdp.

I `sudo apt purge xrdp xfce4 xfce4-goodies -y` and then I rebooted the server.  No errors, showed that everything was uninstalled.

I then reinstalled xrdp with `sudo apt install xrdp`, added the ssl-cert, made sure the xrdp service was running.  However when I xrdp into this computer it still loads up the xfce desktop!

What am I missing in terms of uninstalling xfce?  Is there a setting within ubuntu GUI that I can  tweak to set xrdp back to the gnome desktop, or something on the CLI I can use?